# Description box input for photo uploads

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I found this code on one of the many websites I have visited tonight. I am trying to set up a photo upload page in google drive, creating a dropbox.

I am trying to get the info I put into my placeholder box, city and year to attach to the uploaded photos when they get uploaded. So I can run this and I can upload multiple images to the dropbox, but none of the description info gets attached to the files?

SERVER.GS --------------------------------------------------------------

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName) {
  try{
    var splitBase = base64Data.split(','),
        type = splitBase[0].split(';')[0].replace('data:','');

    var byteCharacters = Utilities.base64Decode(splitBase[1]);
    var ss = Utilities.newBlob(byteCharacters, type);
    ss.setName(fileName);

    var dropbox = "Google_Dropbox"; // Folder Name
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    var file = folder.createFile(ss);

    return file.getName();
  }catch(e){
    return 'Error: ' + e.toString();
  }
}
```

FORM.HTML --------------------------------------------------------------

```html
<body>
  

<p><img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1pOGa76Nssu6hVij_dsrEb8H&sz=w1000-h300" align="center"></p>
  

     <form id="myForm" align="center"> 
     <input type="text" name="myName" style="font-size: 15pt; height: 30px; width:500px "placeholder="Meeting City & Meeting Year">
     

     <label for="myFile">Upload Photo(s):</label>
      
     <input type="file" name="filename" id="myFile" multiple>

     <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="iteratorFileUpload()">

  <div id="output"></div>
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress-label"></div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>

var numUploads = {};
numUploads.done = 0;
numUploads.total = 0;

// Upload the files into a folder in drive
// This is set to send them all to one folder (specificed in the .gs file)
function iteratorFileUpload() {
    var allFiles = document.getElementById('myFile').files;

    if (allFiles.length == 0) {
        alert('No file selected!');
    } else {
        //Show Progress Bar

        numUploads.total = allFiles.length;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value : false
        });//.append("<div class='caption'>37%</div>");
        $(".progress-label").html('Preparing files for upload');
        // Send each file at a time
        for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}

function sendFileToDrive(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var content = reader.result;
        console.log('Sending ' + file.name);
        var currFolder = 'Google_Dropbox';
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function updateProgressbar( idUpdate ){
   console.log('Received: ' + idUpdate);
   numUploads.done++;
   var porc = Math.ceil((numUploads.done / numUploads.total)*100);
   $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: porc });
   $(".progress-label").text(numUploads.done +'/'+ numUploads.total);
   if( numUploads.done == numUploads.total ){
      // uploadsFinished();
      numUploads.done = 0;
   };
}
</script>

  <script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    input {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      ‌​ -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    select {
      margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto !important;
      display: block !important;
    }
    input[type="file"] {
      padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px !important;
    }
#progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.progress-label {
      float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
          width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve your description input box onSubmit, pass it to Apps Script and append its value to the file with `file.setDescription()`. To do so

### Implement the following modifications:

- In function `iteratorFileUpload()` add the line

`var description = document.getElementsByName('myName')[0].value;`

- Modify

`function sendFileToDrive(file)`

to

`function sendFileToDrive(file, description)`

- Call within `function iteratorFileUpload()`

`sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i], description);`

instead of

`sendFileToDrive(allFiles[i]);`

- Call within

`function sendFileToDrive(file, description)`

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, description);`

instead of

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProgressbar).uploadFileToDrive(content, file.name, currFolder);`

- Within your gs. file change

`function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName)`

to

`function uploadFileToDrive(base64Data, fileName, description)`

- Add after

`var file = folder.createFile(ss);`

the line

`file.setDescription(description);`